# Sort multi dimensional string array C#

Tags: c#-3.0

Here is an example array:

{string[2, 22]}

```
[0, 0]: "AA"

[0, 1]: "ZZ"

[0, 2]: "AA"

[0, 3]: "ZZ"

[0, 4]: "AA"

[0, 5]: "ZZ"

[0, 6]: "AA"

[0, 7]: "ZZ"

[0, 8]: "AA"

[0, 9]: "ZZ"

[0, 10]: "AA"   

[1, 0]: "Ken"

[1, 1]: "Tom"

[1, 2]: "Rom"

[1, 3]: "Som"

[1, 4]: "Sam"

[1, 5]: "Kkk"

[1, 6]: "zzz"

[1, 7]: "Aan"

[1, 8]: "Rome"

[1, 9]: "Sammy"

[1, 10]: "Tanny"
```

This can have different rows or can also have more columns. But what i am trying to do is sort the array on rows which contain AA & ZZ and sort acending on that.

Is there any easier way to do that? I tried converting this to an enumerable and do .sort that did not work. I also tried few lambda expressions but i am not sure how to find out which row contains all AA and ZZ columns to sort.

Comment: So you're trying to get all AA's in front, all ZZ's after, and then all theo thers?
or just AA , others, ZZ?

Comment: Could you give a desired output?